# htaccess remove param key not working as intended

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have in place a rewrite rule to remove a key on one of the sites.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /i/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I now want to add this rule.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /stash/index.php?sid=$1 [NC,L]
```

However, this does not work.

```
HOST_NAME/stash/123 will not work.
HOST_NAME/stash?sid=123 will.
```

The PHP is simple....

```
echo $_GET['sid'];
```

Here is my full HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?hostname\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.hostname.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /i/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /stash/index.php?sid=$1 [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /results/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Any help on this would be great.

UPDATE

There are four main directories on the website.

```
/results
/i
/stash
/account
```

I dont care if `/results` shows `?id=1$store=1...etc`

I dont want /i and /stash to show that. I would want those to look like...

```
/i/123456789 instead of /i?id=123456789
/stash/hgdG54Hj9 instead of /stash?sid=hgdG54Hj9
```

Comment: You cannot have 2 different targets for `RewriteRule ^(.*)$`. You already had `/i/index.php?id=$1` before so it is going to work for only that one.

Comment: @anubhava how do I fix this?

Comment: Fix can be done only after you refine your requirements. If you get URL as `/foobar` how it should be handled?

Comment: please see my edits @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have nice directory based URI structures. In that case you can just have a per directory .htaccess

You may use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(hostname\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Inside `stash/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And similarly inside `i/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: results should belong here because results may have upto 5 params. I need it more for /i and /stash. /account will ONLY have directories. /account | /account/giveaway etc

Comment: ok in that case change last rule to: `RewriteRule ^(i|stash)/(.*)$ $1/index.php?id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: this unfortunately didn't work... but i did get it to work by including a htaccess in the /stash directory.

Comment: Yes if you are ready to have .htaccess in each sub directory then it will be even more simplified. Let me update